# Sub class call parent class recursion java

Tags: java, class, exception, stack-overflow

Happy new year guys :-)
I need your help to understand my mistake.

I created board class and cell class who extended the board class, and in the board class I also have an array of the cells.
When I run my code I got java.lang.StackOverflowError exception.

board class:

```
Cell boardGame[][] = new Cell[8][8];

public Board() {
    /*
     * for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j <
     * board[i].length; j++) { board[i][j] = "-"; }
     */
    reorder();
    printBoard();
}

public void reorder() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        boardGame[1][i] = new Cell((new Pawn(ChessPiece.PAWN, Color.BLACK)), 1, i);
        boardGame[6][i] = new Cell((new Pawn(ChessPiece.PAWN, Color.WHITE)), 6, i);
    } 
{...}
```

Cell class:

```
public Cell(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        position = new MoveSet(xPosition, yPosition);
        color = null;
        display = null;
    }

    public Cell(Soldier soldier, int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        this(xPosition, yPosition);
        this.soldier = soldier;
        setRoleMark();
    }

{...}
```

When I try to debug I notice that my Cell constructor go to the Board constructor and run reorder() again, then it create another Cell constructor that go to the Board constructor and run reorder again...

I realized it's a terrible design because my Cell class doesn't need anything from the Board class anyway, but I want to understand why it happened.
I never called super, so why my cell class call the board constructor?

My guess is that every Cell try to create Cell `boardGame[][] = new Cell[8][8]` from it super class (because sub class got the super variable right?) so it basically trying to create itself.

But I am not sure, can you approve it to me?

Thanks,
Or

Comment: In what way is a `Cell` possibly a subclass of `Board`?  That is your fundamental error.  A `Board` is a container for `Cell` objects but a `Cell` is not a type of `Board`.

Comment: If Cell "is a" Board, Board's constructor calls reorder, creating more cells, starting from the beginnig endlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because Java calls `super()` implicitly as the first action of a constructor, if you don't do it yourself.

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

See here for full reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.5

---

As a side-note, asides from that it is a bad idea to have `Cell` extend `Board` you might want to move your generation of the board into a static factory method and leave he `Board()` constructor pretty much empty. That way you will never run into these *hidden* side-effects.

Comment: So it called super on the constructor automatically? Interesting.
Because I see a lot of code start with super() on the subclass constructor.
If it's without any special parameters its pointless..

Answer (score 1):

In java any subclass construction must be after superclas constructor call, if you are not calling super constructor explicitly java by default constructs superclass via default constructor.